# Is the collocation "rekindle a relationship" mostly British

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

I have read this verb in newspapers many times where it is used mostly as synonym of *restart* and it is collocates with relationship.For example if a couple break up and then if they become couple again as far as I know *they rekindle the relationship*..

But somehow when I mentioned this verb in this sense to my American friend, she struggled to understand at first and then she said we can use it like *start a fire*. Then I said probably it is used in metaphorical way when it is collocated with the word relationship.

So I would like to say especially native Americans, do you use the word rekindle in the sense I mention?Is it mostly a British word?

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rekindle

http://www.wikihow.com/Rekindle-a-Relationship

Comment: Rekindle is used commonly in reference to love and romance in the US, probably more often than to physical relight a fire; I'm genuinely surprised she was confused.  It's not the best method, but if you type "rekindle" into Google's search box, several of the automatic search suggestions offer the metaphorical usage, and many of those lead to American pages.

Comment: By “collocation” do you mean “phrase” or “idiom”? “Collocation” as linguists use the term is specialized jargon, not common knowledge. It's the sort of jargon term that begs for misunderstanding. Different linguists define it differently and confusingly: “Use of the term _collocation_…varies depending on the writer’s research priorities. [Some] refer to one type of word combination…others adopt it as a broadly inclusive term…[etc.]” [ [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jc7pYVzjJ2UC&lpg=PA14&dq=collocation%20linguistics&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=collocation%20linguistics&f=false)]

Comment: *Collocation* is fine here.  There's no need to replace it with *idiom* or *phrase*, both of which are also specialized terms in linguistics with different definitions in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Searching the [Corpus of Global Web-Based English (GloWbE)](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=37200199) for `[rekindle] * [relationship]`:

```
  United States     27 results (out of 253,536,242 total words)
  Great Britain     31 results (out of 255,672,390 total words)
```

We find that it's used on both sides of the Atlantic with roughly the same frequency.

I'm an American English speaker, and I expect *all* American English speakers to be familiar with this phrase.  I'm not sure why your friend was confused.

Comment: Anything for which fire is a metaphor can be rekindled. *Love* and *hate* burn hotter than *relationship*, so are slightly more idiomatic

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's mostly British, and would have thought it was reasonably common in American. (I certainly got it instantly.) Perhaps the Amazon Kindle e-reader has begun replacing the verb in people's minds?

Comment: Whenever I see the word *kindle* used in a novel, I am reminded of the Amazon product (that I am probably using to read the novel). Maybe *rekindle* has a meaning re: the Amazon product? ;)

Comment: No, the Amazon product doesn't use "rekindle" for anything specialized. I believe they *have* used it in the usual metaphoric definition, though, in some of their ads. "Rekindle a love of reading" or some-such.

Answer (score 1):

It is an English word, including an American English one.

A way to check and see if something is used in American English is to check an American English dictionary, or one configured to give American English uses.

Whereas dictionaries are not geared toward specific collocations, the first two dictionaries listed below give example sentences with analogous collocations. One could check Ngrams for current usage of a specific collocation.

ODO *US English* [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rekindle)

M-W dictionary [definition](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/Rekindle)

American Heritage dictionary [definition](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Rekindle&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

However, most good dictionaries will specify whether something is an AmE usage or an BrE usage, including the

Cambridge dictionary [public school](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/public-school?q=Public+school), which is totally different in the UK and the US.

On second thought the Cambridge *AmE* dictionary does not give both [meanings](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/public-school).

Although both the *M-W For Learners* and *American Heritage* does. As does the ODO of *British and International English*, the three I cited at first. In fact the ODO *AmE* also gives both definitions.

So it seems Cambridge chooses (at least sometimes) to particularize, while others tend to generalize. I prefer the Cambridge for many of its definitions, but around here the ODO seems more popular.

*Fag* is another word that has BrE-specific (if not AmE-specific meanings), and all the dictionaries listed here touch on both.

Comment: Thank you.I do exactly what you advice when I am confused if a word is used in the US but dictionaries  mostly do not explain  how common is the US, if a word  is mostly British and . Actually my question is about a collation if you read it.

Comment: And when it comes to Google Ngram I am also skeptical about it because for example a word could seem to be common because there is a very famous song which has the same name.

Comment: @Murat I think you are wise to be skeptical of careless use of Ngram to answer questions about usage and meaning. In this case, though, if there's a famous song with the same name, then the phrase is probably well known.